# Align GridView items in Center

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am new to android and developing one Quotes Card Maker Application. I have used GridView for display stickers with 5 Column. I am unable to arrange all columns in center of GridView . I have searched lot of and tried to make it center but its always stay in left side of GridView like this image
[image]

My Item XML is like below

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnr_sticker"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image_sticker"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and GridView is like below

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/framecaregory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/second"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewcategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lite_color"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know what I am missing. Thanks a lot to all friends who trying to help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to change your xml file like below,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnr_sticker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image_sticker"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you, if not than let me know...

Comment: Hi @Priya can u try with relative layout...check edited ans

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lnr_sticker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image_sticker"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

gridview like

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/framecaregory"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/second"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridviewcategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lite_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone">

</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks but still same as before :(

Comment: remove this line in imageView `android:scaleType="fitXY"`